# glassfish v2 in Netbeans 7.2

Tags: plugins, netbeans, glassfish-2.x

I've updated `Netbeans 6.9` to `Netbeans 7.2`. But after that I cannot use glassfish v2 with new Netbeans. The problem is glassfish server v2 is not supported to Netbeans 7.2

The proposed solution of this problem is to add a plugin

http://deadlock.netbeans.org/hudson/job/nbms-and-javadoc/lastStableBuild/artifact/nbbuild/nbms/updates.xml

But it doesn't work for me. I tried it today but it didn't find any such plugin! I guess, it is removed from the repository.

Please anyone give me a suggestion how to resolve the problem now. I am stuck for the whole day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to manually install the Netbeans plugin from here:
http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/netbeans/updates/6.9/uc/m1/dev/modules/enterprise/org-netbeans-modules-j2ee-sun-appsrv81.nbm

Download that file locally and then from NB:

Tools-Plugins-Downloaded - Add Plugins

That fixed it for my NB 7.3.1.

Comment: Successfuly tested on NetBeans 8.0.2 and GlassFish 2.1.1.