# Unable to add Glassfish v2.1.1 server to NetBeans 7.3.1. - ClassNotFoundException

Tags: netbeans-7, glassfish-2.x

I downloaded Glassfish v2.1.1 server from [here](http://dlc-cdn.sun.com/javaee5/v2.1.1_branch/promoted/Linux/)
and followed this [installation instructions](https://glassfish.java.net/downloads/v2ur2-b04.html).
Also, I added the "Glassfish v1, v2x" plugin: `org-netbeans-modules-j2ee-sun-appsrv81.nbm` to NetBeans 7.3.1.
The problem appears when I try to add GlassFish v2.1.1 through the Add server instance dialog in  NetBeans 7.3.1. This is the exception I get:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.netbeans.modules.glassfish.eecommon.api.RegisterDatabase
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.loadClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:222)
Caused: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.netbeans.modules.glassfish.eecommon.api.RegisterDatabase starting from ModuleCL@156d4d5[org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.sun.appsrv81] with possible defining loaders [ModuleCL@171098d[org.netbeans.modules.glassfish.eecommon]] and declared parents [ModuleCL@1037517[org.netbeans.modules.project.ant], ModuleCL@481b29[org.openide.loaders], ModuleCL@ed723b[org.netbeans.api.debugger.jpda], org.netbeans.MainImpl$BootClassLoader@1eb1dbd, ModuleCL@188fa1d[org.jdesktop.layout], ModuleCL@c92353[org.openide.awt], ModuleCL@9b3e9e[org.openide.text], ModuleCL@9c4789[org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.sun.ddui], ModuleCL@4b38f9[org.netbeans.modules.j2eeserver], ModuleCL@1dcd634[org.netbeans.api.java.classpath], ...24 more]
    at org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.loadClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:224)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
Caused: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/netbeans/modules/glassfish/eecommon/api/RegisterDatabase
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.sun.ide.j2ee.ui.AddDomainWizardIterator.createIP(AddDomainWizardIterator.java:395)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.sun.ide.j2ee.ui.AddDomainWizardIterator.createInstance(AddDomainWizardIterator.java:362)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.sun.ide.j2ee.ui.AddDomainWizardIterator.instantiate(AddDomainWizardIterator.java:301)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.impl.bridge.BridgingServerWizardProvider$InstantiatingIteratorBridge.instantiate(BridgingServerWizardProvider.java:101)
    at org.netbeans.modules.server.ui.wizard.AddServerInstanceWizard$AddServerInstanceWizardIterator.instantiate(AddServerInstanceWizard.java:409)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor.callInstantiateOpen(WizardDescriptor.java:1590)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor.callInstantiate(WizardDescriptor.java:1531)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor.access$2200(WizardDescriptor.java:90)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor$Listener$2$1.run(WizardDescriptor.java:2171)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1432)
[catch] at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:2044)
```

Comment: Better try to install server when installing netbeans as it asks for installing Glassfish and Apache Tomcat. There is a bug in Netbeans which usually occurs when integrating modules externally. Try to reinstall and see.

Answer (score 1):

Try to manually install the Netbeans plugin from here: http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/netbeans/updates/6.9/uc/m1/dev/modules/enterprise/org-netbeans-modules-j2ee-sun-appsrv81.nbm

Download that file locally and then from NB:

Tools-Plugins-Downloaded - Add Plugins

That fixed it for my NB 7.3.1.

(see also [glassfish v2 in Netbeans 7.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16419034/glassfish-v2-in-netbeans-7-2/17611916#17611916))

Comment: I quote: /////

    Try to manually install the Netbeans plugin from here:     http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/netbeans/updates/6.9/uc/m1/dev/modules/enterprise/org-netbeans-modules-j2ee-sun-appsrv81.nbm

/////

This URL is now dead.

Does anybody know where this plugin can be downloaded from ?

Answer (score 1):

The location for downloading the "GlassFish v1, v2.x" plugin has changed.

The plugin file: 
org-netbeans-modules-j2ee-sun-appsrv81.nbm
Can now be downloaded from:
http://updates.netbeans.org/netbeans/updates/7.0/uc/final/certified/modules/extra/org-netbeans-modules-j2ee-sun-appsrv81.nbm

Reference:
https://community.oracle.com/thread/3904237

To manually install a downloaded NetBeans plugin:
Tools -> Plugins -> Downloaded -> Add Plugins